User flows and custom user task implementation using Camunda 8
I want to control the user flow in my application using BPMN. Attached is my current BPMN diagram design, which combines service and user tasks. I’m developing a custom web application where the sequence of input screens needs to be configurable.
Here’s how I plan to achieve this:
Upon receiving a request, my backend will instantiate the appropriate process diagram.
Based on the next user task (configured with an external form reference via Zeebe/Worker), the backend will execute the task and render the corresponding UI using the returned JSON data.
For task transitions, I am utilizing different boundary message events, which are triggered by action buttons on the rendered UI.
Challenges I’m Facing:

I’m uncertain about which type of user task to use—Zeebe’s native
user task or the soon-to-be-deprecated worker-based tasks with
custom form references.
While I can target specific types for service tasks, I’m unable to
achieve similar targeting for user tasks based on a specific custom form reference.
I’m questioning whether this approach is fully achievable with BPMN alone or if adjustments are required.

I would appreciate your feedback and suggestions on addressing these issues.

Alternatively, the following could be a possible solution if I use Service Tasks, but it became very complex. Need suggestions.

